# How to display 2 modals on one page aligning one left and other right in bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to display 2 modals, on same screen left and right.. please guide me how to do such thing as i'm new to bootstrap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code inside click function:

```
$("#modal1").modal("show");
$("#modal2").modal("show");
```

And using Css you can position both of them on side by side..

Comment: <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal1">Open Modal 1</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal2">Open Modal 2</button>